# Who was Mahabali in his past life?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas

Are there records in the Puranas of how Mahabali Raj attained his glorious position through some pious Dharmic activity in the past?

Comment: I can't remember exactly but it was stated in some Purana that Bali in his past life was a human with a loose character. In an intoxicated state, while he was going to visit a prostitute to gift flowers, some fell onto the ground & he in his drunken state uttered शिवार्पणमस्तु. Srishankara was pleased with this offering & granted him the status of Indra. But Indra stated that such a precedent would have adverse consequences in future, so Srishankara decreed that the man would attain Indrahood temporarily in his next birth & become Indra of the next manvantara after that temporary stint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Summary is as follows.:**

Mahabali was a gambler in previous life, once he lost all his belongings to some robbers and at his last moment by mistake worshipped Lord Shiva. So, he got Indra's position for almost an hour and half where he donated everything to the rishis out of devotion to Lord Shiva. Thus, got free from his sins by donation and in his next birth became Mahabali.

You can read the story In [Skanda Purana 1.1.18. verse 45](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc365965.html) onwards.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Great thank Your!

Comment: .Welcome. .. .